# How to split string with the values in their specific columns indexed on their label?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have the following data

```
Index   Data
0       100CO
1       50CO-50PET
2       98CV-2EL
3       50CV-50CO
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

I have to create split the data format into different columns each with their own header and their values, the result should be as below:

```
Index   Data          CO        PET      CV    EL
0       100CO         100       0        0     0
1       50CO-50PET    50        50       0     0
2       98CV-2EL      0         0        98    2
3       50CV-50CO     50        0        50    0
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

The data is not limited to CO/PET/CV/EL, will need as many columns needed each displaying its corresponding value.

The `.str.split('-', expand=True)` function will only delimit the data and keep all first values in same column and does not rename each column.

Is there a way to implement this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is first split values by `-`, then extract numbers and no numbers values to tuples, append to list and convert to dictionaries. It is passed in list comprehension to `DataFrame` cosntructor, replaced misisng values and converted to numeric:

```
import re

def f(x):
    L = []
    for val in x.split('-'):
        k, v = re.findall('(\d+)(\D+)', val)[0]
        L.append((v, k))
    return dict(L)

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([f(x) for x in df['Data']], index=df.index).fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
         Data   CO  PET  CV  EL
0       100CO  100    0   0   0
1  50CO-50PET   50   50   0   0
2    98CV-2EL    0    0  98   2
3   50CV-50CO   50    0  50   0
```

If in data exist some values without number or number only solution should be changed for more general like:

```
print (df)
         Data
0       100CO
1  50CO-50PET
2    98CV-2EL
3   50CV-50CO
4         AAA
5          20

def f(x):
    L = []
    for val in x.split('-'):
        extracted = re.findall('(\d+)(\D+)', val)
        if len(extracted) > 0:
            k, v = extracted[0]
            L.append((v, k))
        else:
            if val.isdigit():
                L.append(('No match digit', val)) 
            else:
                L.append((val, 0))
    return dict(L)
    

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([f(x) for x in df['Data']], index=df.index).fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
         Data   CO  PET  CV  EL  AAA  No match digit
0       100CO  100    0   0   0    0               0
1  50CO-50PET   50   50   0   0    0               0
2    98CV-2EL    0    0  98   2    0               0
3   50CV-50CO   50    0  50   0    0               0
4         AAA    0    0   0   0    0               0
5          20    0    0   0   0    0              20
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
df.Data.str.split('-').explode().str.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)',expand = True). \
   reset_index().pivot('index',1,0).fillna(0).reset_index()

1  Index   CO  CV EL PET
0      0  100   0  0   0
1      1   50   0  0  50
2      2    0  98  2   0
3      3   50  50  0   0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately when concat with initial database, index donot match.

Comment: you just remove the `index` name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':['100CO', '50CO-50PET', '98CV-2EL', '50CV-50CO']})

split_df = pd.DataFrame(df.Data.apply(lambda x: {re.findall('[A-Z]+', el)[0] : re.findall('[0-9]+', el)[0] \
                                  for el in x.split('-')}).tolist())
split_df = split_df.fillna(0)

df = pd.concat([df, split_df], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately when concat with initial database, index donot match.